# Executing get with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I execute the function like this:

```
     var path2='//www.example.com/vids/getvid.php?sitename=mysite&amp;vidnum=2';



  $.get(path2,function(data){ });
```

and tehn if the response is positive (no fail)..

I put the path2www, into an iframe to display:

```
                  $('#VideoTutorialTitle').after("<iframe class='video-iframe'  src='"+path2+"' border='0' scrolling='no' id='video_embed2' frameBorder='0'></iframe>");
```

However, when i do that, it fails to fetch the url.. is there a problem of encoding..please help

Comment: try "append" instead of "after"

Comment: Have you tried to examine the DOM element (VideoTutorialTitle) after your function executes successfully to see what the src attribute is?

Comment: -1, not enough data - post the full example

Comment: As mentioned, youre using `after` in the wrong way. Use `append`. Also, replace single quotes for double quotes and vice versa. The URL doesn't exist etc etc...

Comment: just curious why did you put the // before the www in the path2 url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should check ur url!

```
$(function(){
var src = "http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k";
    $.get(src, function(data) {
       // alert(data);
       src = data;
    });
    $('#VideoTutorialTitle').after("<iframe class='video-iframe' src='" + src + "' border='0' scrolling='no' id='video_embed2' frameBorder='0'></iframe>");
});
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6zsmk/6/